# How to load a CSV in segments/parts into a nested list/2D array?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nested

Sorry if I might use the wrong terms, but I'm trying to figure out how to load a CSV into a nested list/2D array in a certain amount of (time)steps.
So please give a shout if I need to edit/add something!

To clarify.... My CSV has a shape of (63564, 78) that consists of short video files that has been processed towards human joint keypoints:

```
import pandas as pd
keypoints = pd.read_csv('keypoints_new.csv')

Frame  ,  NoseX , NoseY  , NoseC   , SchoulderX ..., Label, MovementID
   1   , 901.059, 336.042, 0.935647,  901.166   ..., Plie , Plie_1
   2   , 901.027, 336.078, 0.938929,  901.162   ..., Plie , Plie_1
  ...
  113  , 880.452, 406.757, 0.972856,  904.148   ..., Plie , Plie_32
  ...
  80   , 902.089, 263.018, 0.958629,  845.364   ..., Jete , Jete_20
  ...
```

I hope the above structure makes sense, but basically it's a list of # Frame per video (MovementID) with 75 rows of joint coordinates and at the end the (3 different) label that is just the generic movement for later use.
For my deep learning network, I want to load this data in timesteps in a nested list/2D array.
For example if I want the frames to load per 60 lines/timesteps per MovementID for 123 frames, the structure would be like:

```
#random numbers
Plie_1 - 123 frames - 75 datapoints per line:
[[83, 91, 1, ..., 1253, 927],
[73, 8, 15, ..., 55, 927],
[711, 632, 71]]

Plie_2 - 184 frames:
[[124, 256, 8, ..., 1187, 987],
[37, 45, 13, ..., 12, 987],
[86, 4, 745, ..., 63, 196]
[452, 872, 91, 80]]
etc
```

The remaining lines will be filled with 0's by using Keras padding sequence data so that it will have the same length, but that is a problem for later ;)

I'm aware it probably is achieved by using a for loop, but currently I'm unaware how to split it in those timesteps and converting it straight into a nested list per MovementID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas to load the csv, then create new data frames using the MovementID and then convert those data frames to ndarrays using as_matrix()

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
c = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b']
val = list(zip(a, b, c))
df = pd.DataFrame(val, columns=['num1', 'num2', 'MovementID'])

list_dfs = []
for v in df['MovementID'].unique().tolist():
    new_df = df[df['MovementID'] == v].drop(columns='MovementID').as_matrix()
    list_dfs.append(new_df)
    print('MovementID =', v)
    print(new_df)
```

output:

```
MovementID = a
[[1 1]
 [3 4]]
MovementID = b
[[2 3]
 [6 7]]
MovementID = c
[[4 5]]
MovementID = d
[[5 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, unless I'm mistaken, but this is just for reading the CSV that pandas already does fine? But I do not know how do the import by splitting it per MovementID and based on a set of (time)steps, something with modulo/remainders?

Comment: I posted an answer to help you split by MovementID, but I am not sure what you mean by basing it on the timestep.. hopefully this helps you in some way get an idea

Comment: Yeah, for what I'm seeing as output I think it works! Thank you, 1 step further ;)
What I mean by splitting based on timesteps is that currently every MovementID is in it's own list of all the frames in there --> which vary per video (MovementID) 
But I need to get a list per amount of timesteps per MovementID. This is due the fact that I'm trying to run an LSTM model with certain timesteps that describe one movement..... if that makes sense